# How to Support an iOS app for iPhone,iPad and iPad Mini

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-universal-app, ipad-mini

I Got the requirement to create an iOS universal app which Should Support for iPhone,
  iPad and iPad mini.

Now How to Include the support for iPad mini in universal app

Is the development screen sizes are same for iPad mini?

Any suggestions please?

Comment: It's the same size:)

Comment: In xcode6 if you use autolayout or auroresizing it works for all resolutions

Comment: But I m working on Xcode 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the autoresizing functionnalities of Xcode 5.1.
You can specify the behavior of your views according to the screen resizing. I used this to adapt my app to the iPad mini.

You can specify if your view width's grows or not, stick to border, etc.

[image]

You can enable it by disabling Autolayout for the controller.

Comment: I don't disagree but shouldn't be more phrased like `"Use the autoresizing functionnality introduced in Xcode 5.1."`?

Comment: Added some details but can't be in the head and explain exactly what to do. Take a look, do some test, it's pretty easy to use.